# Audio in 2 monitors using HDMI

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi

I have a VGA card with 3 outputs: HDMI, DVI, VGA. 
I have also two monitors with speakers. My computer runs an Ubuntu 10.10.

When I had only 1 monitor I connected it via HDMI and had video and audio.
I bought a new monitor.

If I conect Monitor1 to DVI and Monitor2 to VGA it works fine but the only way I can have audio is using external speakers.

But I would like to make it better, so I have some questions:

1. **Is possible to connect monitor1
   to HDMI and monitor2 to DVI or VGA?
   (Tried but didn't work DVI/VGA)**
2. **Is possible to have three monitors
   at the same time?**
3. **Is possible to
   have 2 monitors using single HDMI
   and this way having audio in both
   monitors?**

Thanks

Comment: Interesting that you accepted my answer without providing the additional information I asked for...obviously I was some help though so thanks. ;)

Comment: I googled my vga card to see if it could support 3 monitors (it can't). Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question #1 is "almost certainly", but again this depends on the card.  99% of cards should support it.

You need to specify what the card is in order to get an answer to question #2.  Some cards support this, some don't.  Odds are that any card with a VGA port doesn't support three simultaneous outputs, but it might.

Question #3 is "not if you intend to use a DVI-HDMI adapter".  There may be a SPLITTER on the market that'll do this but then you won't have independent desktops, you'll be mirroring.  This also begs the question of "why do you need to pipe your sound to multiple speaker setups?"  Can't you hear it just fine anyway?

Comment: A bit of a necro-comment here, but because DVI and HDMI are electrically similar, in older (say... the time period of the original post) and cheaper cards share circuitry for the two ports and can't push both at the same time. The analog VGA circuitry is not bound in the same way.